# How to rename files in a folder with ".csv" at the end??[R]

Tags: r

```r
setwd("C:\\Users\\Note\\Documents\\Folder")
n <- dir(pattern = ".csv")
names<-as.character(c(1:length(n)))
file.rename(n,names)
```

I am trying to rename several worksheets to an id 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc But when I do this the worksheets are no longer ".csv" files. How to add ".csv" to the rename function?
Is there any way to make "n" stay in sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6, so that if I add a new spreadsheet it will be the last one in "n"?
 n = https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhlyT.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of your third line

```
names <- paste0(1:length(n), ".csv")
```

The numbers will be automatically coerced to character format.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is  `seq_along`  which would be helpful even for a zero length 'n'

```
names <- paste0(seq_along(n), ".csv")
```